# Read NLog configuration from database instead of config file

Tags: .net, configuration, nlog

is it possible to read NLog .NET configurations from database?
My need is to rapidally change the severity of targets rule's, so I'm wondering if there is a way to do that.
For example, if in a configuration file I have this:

```
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Warning" writeTo="LogToDB" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="LogToConsole" />
</rules>
```

I wanna be able to rapidally change **minlevel="*value*"** values (i.e. from database configuration table), without deploy the application configuration file.

Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
<variable name="MinLevelDB" value="Warning" />
<variable name="MinLevelConsole" value="Info" />

<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="${var:MinLevelDB}" writeTo="LogToDB" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="${var:MinLevelConsole}" writeTo="LogToConsole" />
</rules>
```

And then you can do this:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["MinLevelDB"] = "Debug";
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-specific-NLog-Logging-Configuration

Answer (score 2):

You can reconfigure logging at runtime using `APIs` provided by `NLog`.
Use below function to reconfigure logging -

```
public void ReconfigureLoggingLevel()
{
    foreach (var rule in NLog.LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules)
    {
        var logLevel = GetLogLevelFromDatabase(); // your logic to fetch log level
        rule.EnableLoggingForLevel(NLog.LogLevel.FromString(logLevel));
    }
    NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}
```